# absolutely positioned section is messing with the rest of web page

Tags: height, css-position, absolute, sections

I am designing a slideshow and the absolutely positioned ul of images. The absolutely positioned ul is screwing with the natural flow of the rest of the page. I know absolutely positioned elements do this. However, I was under the impression that setting the #sliding section to position: static and having height: auto !important would work. The #stuff section is showing up underneath the #sliding section. Has anybody else had to work with this before?

To be perfectly clear the actual slideshow works perfectly, but the HTML and CSS is what I am trying to solve. Any help is very appreciated.

Here is the HTML

```
    <section id="sliding">

        <img id="leftimg" src="prev.png" alt="left">

        <ul class="boxslider">
            <li><img class="slidingimg" src=".jpg" id="will" alt="1"></li><!-- will -->
            <li><img class="slidingimg" src=".jpg" id="poa" alt="2"></li><!-- powerofattorney -->
            <li><img class="slidingimg" src=".jpg" id="probate" alt="3"></li><!-- probate -->
            <li><img class="slidingimg" src=".jpg" id="forming" alt="4"></li><!-- forming business -->
            <li><img class="slidingimg" src=".jpg" id="contracts" alt="5"></li><!--  -->
            <li><img class="slidingimg" src=".jpg" id="realestate" alt="6"></li><!--  -->
        </ul>

        <img id="rightimg" src="next.png" alt="right">
    </section>

    <section id="stuff">
        <h2>Stuff</h2>
        <h2>Stuff</h2>
        <h2>Stuff</h2>
        <h2>Stuff</h2>
    </section>
```

Here is the CSS

```
#sliding{
    position: static;
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: auto !important;
    clear: both;
}

#leftimg, #rightimg{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#leftimg{
    left: 1vw;
}

#rightimg{
    right: 1vw;
}

.boxslider{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 600vw;
    overflow: none;
}

.slidingimg{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100vw;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}

#stuff{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 80vh;
    border-top: 8px solid green;
    clear: both;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/2ruk3Lju/2/

Comment: Post the code ***here***. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: added the code and clarified the issue even more.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot use position:absolute. Position absolute has to have the height and width explicitly assigned. I decided to try position relative since it can still be moved by jquery to create a sliding effect. This works because position:relative is still within the normal flow of the document and fixes the issue of the content below the #sliding div stacking underneath it.